# Do I need to vacuum-test the lines for a new mini-split?

Tags: installation, mini-split

Sanity check for installing a multi-zone mini-split system:  I pressure test each zone individually.  Then I vacuum each zone and release the refrigerant into that line set (assuming no leaks).  Then open the master valves to release the rest of the refrigerant.  Any need to vacuum test the master valve lines before opening?

Answer (score 2):

Not an HVAC expert - happy to be corrected if there's something I missed here. I have installed more than a handful of systems for myself and friends, and I'm an obsessive researcher. Mitsubishi says just to vacuum test. LG says just to pressure test. I prefer to both vacuum test and pressure test. I've summarized my process below. All vacuum measurements must be made with a micron gauge. Use a gauge manifold to avoid contamination during this process.

1. Evacuate to 4000 microns to remove the bulk water vapor from the lines.
2. Break the vacuum to at least 200 PSIG with dry nitrogen.
3. Leak test the system at all joints with soapy water.
4. Let down the nitrogen pressure to a few PSIG before you switch back to the vacuum pump.
5. Evacuate to 1500 microns or lower.
6. Break the vacuum to 0 PSIG with dry nitrogen.
7. Evacuate to 500 microns. Leave the system for an hour, making sure it doesn't rise above 500 microns. Note that I leave the pump going for a while, basically letting it evacuate down to as hard of a vacuum as my pump can handle after an hour. I've found there will be a small rise right after stopping the pump, then it should hold steady within a minute and stay at that number for the hour.
8. Assuming leak and rise test pass, open the valves.
9. Make sure to rapidly remove the gauges to avoid loss of refrigerant.

This takes a little bit longer than either of the usual procedures, but it catches problems that just one of the two tests might not find.